# Você vai "entrar de férias", "sair de férias" ou "entrar em férias"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palavras

É dezembro e muita gente anda dizendo que vai "entrar de férias", outros vão "sair de férias" e outros, ainda, vão "entrar em férias".  Estariam todos corretos ou apenas alguns vão "curtir" a vida sem ferir o vernáculo?

Comment: Que curioso! "*Entrar*" e "*sair* de férias" é como "*desfazer*" e "*fazer* a barba"...

Comment: Ou ainda "tirar férias" ou "ter férias" ou "vou de férias" ou "vou estar de férias"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Todas as expressões estão corretas e têm o significado que alguém vai ter férias.

A expressão "sair de férias" deve ser mais comumente usada quando alguém quer dar a ideia que vai viajar. [As imagens da pesquisa do Google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sair%20de%20f%C3%A9rias) sugerem exatamente isso.

As expressões "entrar de férias" ou "entrar em férias" são intercambiáveis. Contudo, [este artigo](http://portugues.uol.com.br/gramatica/entrar-ferias-ou-ferias.html) sugere que a expressão "entrar em férias" é a mais recomendada quando é atribuída a um substantivo ou adjetivo. Eles dão os seguintes exemplos:

> Os funcionários sairão em férias **coletivas**.
>
> Após o balanço final, todos estarão em **merecidas** férias.

Comment: "Vão todos querer entrar de férias na mesma data?"