# Afinal o que quer dizer «vernáculo»?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras

Hoje parece ser o dia do vernáculo, vi [nesta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3934/153) e [neste texto de humor](http://porfalarnoutracoisa.sapo.pt/2016/12/carao-fod-se-put-que-pariu.html). O que acabou por me confundir. Fui ao dicionário e qual o meu espanto, vernáculo não se encaixa em nenhum dos textos como eu imaginava.

> #### ver·ná·cu·lo
>
> (latim vernaculus, -a, -um, de escravo nascido em casa, de escravo) adjectivo
>
> 1. Próprio do país ou da nação a que pertence. = NACIONAL
> 2. [Figurado]  Diz-se da linguagem sem incorrecções e sem inclusão de estrangeirismos. = CASTIÇO
> 3. Que se expressa de modo rigoroso e sem incorrecções (ex.: escritor vernáculo). substantivo masculino
> 4. Língua própria de um país ou de uma região
>
> "vernáculo", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/vern%C3%A1culo [consultado em
> 07-12-2016].

Afinal há mais utilizações para vernáculo que não constem no dicionário?

Comment: Nunca me dei ao trabalho de ver o significado no dicionário. Sempre considerei "vernáculo" estar relacionada á palavra "vocabulário" (embora possa ter significado diferente), Repara portanto na segunda definicao `Diz-se da linguagem sem incorrecções e sem inclusão de estrangeirismo` (ou seja o vocabulário, mas com algumas restricoes)

Comment: Usei "vernáculo" na minha pergunta com o sentido 4 do Priberam (língua própria de um país)

Comment: Achei essa frase de imensa sabedoria: "Percebo a sensibilidade ao vernáculo, mas deixem-me dizer que essas pessoas são palermas e que se uma asneira lhes estraga algo «muito bom» então vão passar a vida a queixar-se de muita coisa e a não apreciar os bons momentos."  quando ele se refere a alguém que acha que algo teria sido excelente não fosse um detalhe que estragou tudo.

Comment: @Centaurus No Brasil, *asneira* também significa  'palavrão, palavra obscena'? É com esse significado que é usado pelo autor.

Comment: @Jacinto Não, _asneira_ deste lado do Atlântico significa _besteira_, _estupidez_.

Comment: @Ramon Foi o que eu suspeitei. Eu fiz ctrl F "vernáculo" e fui direito à passagem que o Centaurus cita, e fiquei na dúvida: a "asneira" seria tipo pontapé na gramática que ofenderia o gosto pelo bom vernáculo; ou seria um palavrão que ofenderia quem não gosta de vernáculo (no sentido de 'palavrão). Depois continuei a ler e vi que era a segunda interpretação.

Comment: @Jacinto   É o que o Ramon Melo disse.

Comment: O **vernáculo** é também o **oposto de língua/linguagem ou norma culta**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para além dos significados listados no Priberam, ***vernáculo*** é frequentemente usado com o sentido de ***palavrão***. Não encontrei isto explicado em nenhum dicionário, mas é com este sentido que a palavra é usada no [artigo que lincas](http://porfalarnoutracoisa.sapo.pt/2016/12/carao-fod-se-put-que-pariu.html). Imagino que isto venha do hábito, que me parece mais português que brasileiro, de se invocar ***o bom vernáculo***—a inadulterada língua genuína e castiça—quando no meio de “linguagem séria” se usa um palavrão ou uma expressão popularucha. Exemplos, com negrito meu:

> Na verdade, falando no **bom vernáculo** daqui da terrinha, ele levou mesmo foi um chute no saco, pra deixar de ser tabacudo.
>   [(*Jornal da Besta Fubana*, 2013.)](http://www.luizberto.com/deu-no-jornal/uma-pesada-na-bolsa-escrotal)
>
> E a mim só me apetece lançar mão do **bom vernáculo** e mandá-los foder.
>   [(Blog *Ladrar à Lua*, 2016.)](http://ladraralua.blogspot.pt/2016/04/ta-bonita-brincadeira.html)
>
> Através do vidro aberto, põe o nariz dentro do carro, para que a sua indicação sobre a localização do hotel que procuramos, gritada entre **interjeições do bom vernáculo minhoto**, seja bem compreendida. **"São portugueses, c....?"** [(*Visão*, 2009.)](http://visao.sapo.pt/actualidade/sociedade/andorra-o-pais-dos-portugueses=f503408)

É claro que vernáculo inclui linguagem quer popular quer erudita; quer grosseira quer diplomática. Mas desta invocação do “bom vernáculo” terá surgido o uso figurado de *vernáculo* com o sentido de ‘palavrão’. Exemplo de [Clara Ferreira Alves no *Expresso* (2015, via Ciberdúvidas)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/idioma/o-palavrao-na-selva-digital/3143):

> A frase mais usada era Vai para o car…lho, f…da-se! Frase que costuma ser dita com graciosidade para as bandas do Porto. E aqui, como se vê, tenho de colocar reticências. É de bom tom nos jornais colocar reticências [...] Ninguém ousa escrever como um reles comentador de pé de página. Ou puxar para título **o vernáculo**. Imagine-se o título Fulano f…deu-se!

Comment: Então, pelo que eu entendi, vernáculo acaba por adquirir esse significado muito por causa do vernáculo portuense (do norte) rico em palavrões?

Comment: @JorgeB. Isso agora, não sei qual é a contribuição relativa de cada região. Os palavrões do norte são mais ou menos os mesmos que os do sul e até os do Brasil; talvez os usem mais, não sei. Isto de invocar o "bom vernáculo" para justificar o uso dum palavrão é feito um bocado por graça, creio.