# How do I say have a good holiday?

Tags: português-europeu

"Holiday" as in break from school. Like half term. I don't want to accidentally say holiday as in to go somewhere else kind of holiday. .

Tenha uma boa pausa? 
Tenha um bom feriado?

Comment: Do you want to say holiday like 4th of July or holiday like 2 weeks term?

Answer (score 4):

If you are referring to just one day (not weekend) "**Feriado**" will be appropriate. "Tenha um bom feriado"

If you are referring to a longer period (not weekend) "**Férias**" will be the best word to use. "Tenha umas boas férias"

Comment: I think this answer would be better if it had the whole sentence: "Tenha um bom feriado."

Comment: You went for a word-for-word translation. I would say the most natural way of wishing someone a nice holiday is simply, "boas férias".

Comment: I agree with that in a uninformal environment we can use it. @Jacinto

Answer (score 3):

This question somewhat relates to [a previously asked question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3934/voc%C3%AA-vai-entrar-de-f%C3%A9rias-sair-de-f%C3%A9rias-ou-entrar-em-f%C3%A9rias).

In Portuguese the most common translation for holiday is "férias". It can also be "feriado", if you are referring to a specific holiday such as the Christmas holiday (feriado de Natal). Therefore you can not really use "feriado" here.

The most commonly used sentence should be

> Tenha umas boas férias (Have a nice holiday)

This sentence does not imply that the person will travel.

However, like the question I mentioned states, there is a slight difference between saying

> Vou sair de férias (I am going on vacation)

and

> Vou ter férias (I am going to have holidays)

Comment: Eu tinha dito o mesmo, mas depois fiquei na dúvida se referia à pausa letiva ou ao feriado em si.

Comment: You went for a word-for-word translation. I would say the most natural way of wishing someone a nice holiday is simply, "boas férias".

Answer (score 2):

I gather you mean "away from school during a period when most academic activities are interrupted", vacation in AmE, and holidays in BrE. **An enthusiastic "boas férias"** is what most people say. **It's simple, idiomatic and that's what I usually say to friends, acquaintances and fellow workers.**  Of course there are several other phrases to convey the same, but some of them are unusual.

- "tenha umas boas férias"
- "desejo boas férias pra ti"
- "aproveite bem as férias"
- "bom descanso nas férias"
- "divirta-se bastante"
- "férias é algo sempre bom. Nem é preciso dizer o 'boas'."